# how can i create a custom variable for only the second return in a foreach

Tags: php, json, foreach

i am reading a json file file, limiting to 3 returns in a foreach loop, and outputting the results in a html chunk of code. for the second return only, i would like to add a variable for a css class "active", and leave the first and third returns blank. this is not something currently being passed in the json, i just want to make something like (and i know this isn't right):

```
$displayValue[0] = '';
$displayValue[1] = 'active';
$displayValue[2] = '';
```

so that in my html it will output like:

```
<div style="[[+displayValue]]">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's just for style CSS why you don't use :nth-child() ?
https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/nth-child/
In your exemple the code looks like :

```
div:nth-child(2){
    /* your style here */
}
```

if your array keys stay 0, 1, 2, ... you can use Tim Hinz method. But if your keys can change you have to increment a var.

For exemple :

```
<?php 
$increment_var = 0;
foreach($displayValue as $value) {
    if(($increment_var++) == 1) {
        //set your CLASS here, in the above you're setting style to active. You said you needed a class.
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, end of day, having trouble with complete sentences, but this helps, i really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($displayValue as $key => $value) {
    if($key == 1) {
        //set your CLASS here, in the above you're setting style to active. You said you needed a class.
    }
}
```

For how broad this question is, I think this answers what you're asking.